# Error with Dynamics 365 app for Outlook only in Desktop client but works in OWA

Tags: dynamics-crm, server-side-sync, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics365-app-outlook

I have installed & configured the Dynamics 365 app for Outlook with my v9 Org. I have Office 2016 Professional Plus with latest updates.

It's totally working fine in OWA but not even started working on my Laptop Outlook. This is even listed as a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/readme-9#dynamics-365-app-for-outlook), but it says "frequently", for me always.

[image]

I have troubleshooted with the help of below links but no luck:
[Blog](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/adammurchison/2017/12/07/how-to-fix-microsoft-dynamics-365-app-for-outlook-add-in-error) & [Community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/244929/753669)

Anybody know some extra troubleshooting steps to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our environment is having some limitations like 3rd party encryption called Vaultive & then Oauth was not enabled which is a prerequisite for App for Outlook it seems in desktop client (for OWA it's not required just federation is fine).

We are able to sort out these things after MS support ticket & deep internal analysis. Now its working.